# Since '{method}' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#, methods, .net-4.0, compiler-errors, return

I'm trying to return a simple string from an XML file when you call a method after defining the location of the XML file. However, when I try to return, it says that "Since 'CareerDescription()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression". The word return is highlighted red and that's the message. Compiler will say "Method must have a return type". I do have the return type but it doesn't want to return... Here is the code:

```
    public CareerDescription(string CareerFile)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(CareerFile);
        string Description = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Careers/CareerList/CareerDescription").InnerText;
        return Description;
    }
```

I also tried this to see if it was something wrong with the method I created, however I get the same exact error message....

```
    public TestMethod()
    {
        string test = "test";
        if (test == "test")
        {
            return test;
        }
    }
```

And this also gives the same message...

```
    public TestMethod()
    {
        string test = "test";
        return test;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in the creation of my methods? I can't for the life of me figure it out...

Comment: First of all, your "methods" are either constructors or compiler errors, you have not specifiec their return type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a return type

```
       V----V
public string CareerDescription(string CareerFile)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(CareerFile);
    string Description = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Careers/CareerList/CareerDescription").InnerText;
    return Description;
}
```

A method MUST have a return type, so I'm curious what is telling you this:

> "Since 'CareerDescription()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression".

when you omit a return type, as the TRUE error is not the `return`, but the LACK of a return type.

For example this is not legal:

```
public DoNothing()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just added in string and it works perfectly. Thank you very much, also thanks for the explanation, helps a lot.

Comment: I do not understand this. In the question, the return looks like this: `return Description;`. So what is new here? There was an object after the return from the beginning, or am I missing something?

Comment: @questionto42 There is not a return type in the method in the question, and I added one to make it valid (see the `V------V` framing the return type?) - methods in C# require a return type, it cannot be omitted or inferred from the content.

Comment: I had not understood that `V------V`. I have never seen that before, being a beginner at C# I thought it would not make sense to check it. Only now I understand that it is just to show the beginning and the end of that `string`. Well. I had checked the code against the one in question on two screens, and I did oversee this one. My bad.